# why empty slots are being replaced with undefined while cloning array using spread syntax?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm creating a clone array from an array that contain some empty slots. But after cloning it is being replaced with `undefined`. If the source array contain some empty slots then clone array should also contain same number and at exact same position empty slots. I don't get the reason. I'm using [`spread syntax`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) to clone array as:

```
const arr = [1, "", , null, undefined, false, , 0];
console.log('arr => ', arr);

const clone = [...arr];
console.log('clone => ', clone)
```

Output is as below in chrome console

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using spread syntax will invoke the object's iterator if it has one. The [array iterator](https://tc39.es/ecma262/multipage/indexed-collections.html#sec-createarrayiterator) will:

```
a. Let index be 0.
b. Repeat
  Let len be ? LengthOfArrayLike(array).
  iii. If index ≥ len, return NormalCompletion(undefined).
  (...)
    1. Let elementKey be ! ToString((index)).
    2. Let elementValue be ? Get(array, elementKey).
    (yield elementValue)
  vi. Set index to index + 1.
```

And the length of a sparse array is still the index of the last element plus one:

```js
const arr = [];
arr[5] = 'a';
console.log(arr.length);
```

So, even with sparse arrays, spreading them will result in the new array containing values of:

```
arr[0]
arr[1]
arr[2]
// ...
arr[arr.length - 1]
```

even when the original array has empty slots in between 0 and `arr.length - 1`.

If you *want* empty slots, spreading will only work if you delete the undesirable indices afterwards - or iterate over the array manually, only assigning indices you need.

```js
const arr = [1, "", , null, undefined, false, , 0];
console.log('arr => ', arr);

const clone = [];
for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
  if (arr.hasOwnProperty(i)) {
    clone[i] = arr[i];
  }
}
console.log('clone => ', clone)
```

But you could also consider restructuring your code to avoid sparse arrays entirely - they're not very intuitive.

Answer (score 1):

Let's take a step back

```js
let x;
console.log(x); // undefined
console.log(typeof x); // undefined
```

If you don't **define** a variable, it is **un-defined**.

Let's see now an empty array:

```js
let x = [,]; // even [] would work but I thought this one is clearer for some
console.log(x[0]); // undefined
console.log(typeof x[0]); //undefined
```

Why is that? Simply because

> If you don't **define** a variable, it is **un-defined**.

Answer (score 0):

above answers already made it pretty clear why you getting undefiend. 
Just to add more If you log `arr[2]` you will get `undefined`, i haven't read it anywhere but from what i know spread operator spread the values of array/obj that is why `arr[2]` value is `undefiend`